# 2nd Order ODE with Optimal Control

Tags: mathematical-optimization, differential-equations

I'm trying to solve an ODE where there is an optimal control problem involving a tradeoff between the flow cost `c` and the drift rate `g` as well as value matching and smooth pasting conditions characterizing the boundary value `xbar`.  Something like the following:

```
0 == c[a, x] + f[a, x]*V[x] + g[a, x]*V'[x] + h[x]*V''[x]
V[xbar] == psi[xbar]
V'[xbar] == psi'[xbar]
```

This is a class of problem that often appears in financial economics. I tried to implement this in Mathematica using FindMaximum and NDSolve, but encountered issues. Minimal Example below:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
c[a_, x_] = (1 - a^2/2)*x;
f[x_]     = 1;
g[a_, x_] = a;
h[x_]     = 0.5*x^2;
psi[x_]   = x - 1;
astar[X_?NumericQ, dV_?NumericQ] := 
   With[{xx = X, dvv = dV}, 
    FindMaximum[{c[a, xx] + g[a, xx]*dvv, a >= 0}, {a, 
       1/2}][[2]]]; // Quiet
ODE = {0 == c[a, x] + f[x]*V[x] + g[a, x]*V'[x] + h[x]*V''[x], 
   V[xbar] == psi[xbar], 
   V'[xbar] == psi'[xbar]} /. {a -> astar[x, V'[x]]}
```

I am trying to use a shooting method to evaluate whether my guess of  is too high or too low relative to the condition `V(0) = 0`, and will eventually do this properly using FindRoot.

Trying with a guess of 10 (as in the example) results in errors.  What is the appropriate way to implement this in Mathematica?

EDIT: To provide some more structure to the problem, x is assumed to take values $x \in \left[0, \overline{x}\right]$, and $a$ is restricted to positive values.  In the MWE, I provided a convex cost function $c$ that has support over all nonnegative numbers, but it is equally interesting to consider something of the form $\left(a-\ln\left(1-a\right)\right)x$, which would only take values on the interval $\left[0, 1\right)$.

Comment: You use a definition `f[x_]=1` with one argument, and in the equation you use this function with two arguments `f[a,x]`. How do you solve equation?

Comment: @AlexTrounev ammended to reflect the fact that f is a trivial function of only x. The error was mine.

Comment: It is necessary to formulate the problem correctly or to indicate an article where this task is formulated. We do not even know the interval for x and a.

Comment: Based on @AlexTrounev's request, I've edited the original post to provide more structure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the version of the running code as I understand this task

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
x0 = .1; xbar = .9;
c[a_, x_] := (1 - a^2/2)*x;
f[x_] := 1;
g[a_, x_] := a;
h[x_] := 0.5*x^2;
psi[x_] := x - 1;
astar[X_?NumericQ, dV_?NumericQ] := 
   With[{xx = X, dvv = dV}, 
    FindMaximum[{c[a, xx] + g[a, xx]*dvv, a >= 0}, {a, 
       1/2}][[1]]]; // Quiet
ODE = {c[a, x] + f[x]*V[x] + g[a, x]*V'[x] + h[x]*V''[x] == 0, 
    V[xbar] == psi[xbar], 
    V'[xbar] == psi'[xbar]} /. {a -> astar[x, V'[x]]};
sol = NDSolve[ODE, V, {x, x0, xbar}];

{Plot3D[astar[x, y], {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, Mesh -> None, 
 AxesLabel -> {"x", "y", ""}],Plot[Evaluate[V[x] /. sol], {x, x0, xbar}, AxesLabel -> {"x", "V(x)"}]}
```

[image: fig1]

Comment: This code works, and in particular works even when I allow xbar to be a parameter rather than a predefined constant.  Is there a better way of implementing the Shooting Method to impose the condition `V[0] == 0` inside of NDSolve?  My prior experience was to do it myself using `FindRoot`

Comment: Looking at the code again, is there a reason you have a->astar, where you have changed the definition of astar to be the maximized reward, rather than the optimal control value a?

Comment: To avoid singularity, we must exclude the point x = 0. Note that under the existing conditions and data the set `FindRoot[][[2]]` is empty, so I took the set `FindRoot[][[1]]`. We can not put three boundary conditions for one equation of the second order. There must be a free parameter to execute the third boundary condition, but it is not among the data.

Comment: Assuming I understood you correctly, the free parameter is the choice of `xbar`.  The point regarding the set notation with FindRoot is interesting and one I wasn't aware of.

Comment: You can enter a free parameter in any function, for example, `psi[x_]:= x + k`, then for `k = 2.39` we get `V[0]=0`

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't quite understand how to take your comment and convert that to having NDSolve find xbar.  Could you edit your response to incorporate your suggestion?  I think it's still relevant since I reference implementing the shooting method in the original question.